# MySQL: "Subquery returns more than 1 row" when selecting results of multiple subqueries

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm getting a "`Subquery returns more than 1 row`" error while running a query that's meant to return results of two subqueries. Why is returning more than one row a problem here, and how can I get around this problem?

Data tables and relevant fields look like this:

`Accounts`
*id*

`Meetings`
*account_id

assigned_user_id

start_date*

`Users`
*id

last_name*

A meeting is assigned to an account and to a user. I'm trying to create a table that will display the quantities of meetings per assigned user per account where the meeting start date is within different date ranges. The date ranges should be arranged in the same row, as a table with these headings:

Account | User's Last Name | Meetings 1-31 days in the future | Meetings 31-60 days in the future

as shown in this image:

[image: this image].

This is my query:

```
SELECT
(SELECT
    a.name
  FROM
    accounts AS a
  JOIN
    meetings AS m ON a.id = m.account_id
    AND date_start BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 60 DAY)
  JOIN
    users AS u ON m.assigned_user_id = u.id
  WHERE
    m.status = 'Planned'
    AND m.deleted = 0
GROUP BY a.id, u.id) AS 'Account',
(SELECT
    u.last_name
  FROM
    accounts AS a
  JOIN
    meetings AS m ON a.id = m.account_id
    AND date_start BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 60 DAY)
  JOIN
    users AS u ON m.assigned_user_id = u.id
WHERE
    m.status = 'Planned'
    AND m.deleted = 0
GROUP BY a.id, u.id) AS 'Name',
(SELECT
    COUNT(m.id)
  FROM
    accounts AS a
  JOIN
    meetings AS m ON a.id = m.account_id
    AND date_start BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)
  JOIN
    users AS u ON m.assigned_user_id = u.id
  WHERE
    m.status = 'Planned'
    AND m.deleted = 0
GROUP BY a.id, u.id) AS 'Meetings 1-30 days',
(SELECT
    COUNT(m.id)
  FROM
    accounts AS a2
  JOIN
    meetings AS m ON a.id = m.account_id
    AND m.date_start BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 31 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 60 DAY)
  JOIN
    users AS u ON m.assigned_user_id = u.id
  WHERE
    m.status = 'Planned'
    AND m.deleted = 0
GROUP BY a.id, u.id) AS 'Meetings 31-60 days'
```

Columns containing the names of accounts and names of users had to be added as subqueries in order to avoid "`Operand should contain 1 column(s)`" errors. Columns corresponding to the counts of meetings had to be subqueries because no single row of the joined table can fit both date ranges at the same time. Each subquery returns the expected results when run individually. But I get "`Subquery returns more than 1 row`" when the subqueries are put together as shown. I tried assigning different aliases to each subquery, but that did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL queries do not return nested result sets; so an expression (such as a subquery) used in a SELECT clause cannot have multiple values, as that would "nest" it's values. You more likely just need to use conditional aggregation, like so:

```
SELECT a.id, u.id, a.name, u.last_name
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN m.date_start BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS `Meetings 1-30 days`
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN m.date_start BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 31 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 60 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS `Meetings 31-60 days`
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN  THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 
FROM accounts AS a
JOIN meetings AS m ON a.id = m.account_id
JOIN users AS u ON m.assigned_user_id = u.id
WHERE m.status = 'Planned' AND m.deleted = 0
  AND m.date_start BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 60 DAY)
GROUP BY a.id, u.id, a.name, u.last_name
;
```

Notes: *ELSE NULL* is technically automatic, and can be omitted; it is just there for clarity. Aggregate functions, such as COUNT, ignore NULL values; the only time null values affect such functions is when they encounter only null values (in which case their results are null).

Sidenote: You *could* have continued with your query in a form similar to what you originally had; if you included the grouping fields in the subqueries' results, the subqueries could have been joined together (but that would have been a lot of redundant joining of accounts, meetings, and users).